# Crash in Android location manager

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I am getting following crash stack from Crashlytics:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider doesn't exist: fused
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1687)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
   at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:614)
   at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:887)
   at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:536)
   at org.traccar.client.PositionProvider.startUpdates(PositionProvider.java:72)
```

Device - Motorola Moto C with Android 7.0

Relevant source code fragments:

```
public static Criteria getCriteria(String accuracy) {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    switch (accuracy) {
        case "high":
            criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
            break;
        case "low":
            criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
            break;
        default:
            criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
            break;
    }
    return criteria;
}


public void startUpdates() {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            interval, 0,
            getCriteria(preferences.getString(MainFragment.KEY_ACCURACY, "medium")),
            this, Looper.myLooper());
}
```

I'm not sure what the `accuracy` value is, but I think this error shouldn't happen in any case. If needed, full source can be found [here](https://github.com/traccar/traccar-client-android/blob/v5.12/app/src/main/java/org/traccar/client/PositionProvider.java).

Why is this happening? Android documentation doesn't list this as a possible exception scenario when calling `requestLocationUpdates` method.